# constructor "name" in class "Class name" cannot be applied to given types in Room Persistence Library

Tags: java, android, database

I am creating an entity class using room database entity annotation like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "dropbox_payload")
public class DropboxPayload {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @NonNull
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "tId")
    private String trialId;

    @TypeConverters(DeviceDetailsConverter.class)
    private DeviceDetails deviceDetails;

    @TypeConverters(ContentConverter.class)
    private Map<String, String> content;


    public DropboxPayload(String trialId, DeviceDetails deviceDetails, Map<String, String> content) {
        this.trialId = trialId;
        this.deviceDetails = deviceDetails;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTrialId() {
        return trialId;
    }

    public void setTrialId(String trialId) {
        this.trialId = trialId;
    }

    public DeviceDetails getDeviceDetails() {
        return deviceDetails;
    }

    public void setDeviceDetails(DeviceDetails devices) {
        this.deviceDetails = devices;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(Map<String, String> content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public static class DeviceDetailsConverter {

        @TypeConverter
        public String stringFromDeviceDetails(DeviceDetails value) {
            if (value == null) {
                return null;
            }
            String json = new Gson().toJson(value);
            return json;
        }

        @TypeConverter
        public DeviceDetails personFromString(String value) {
            if (value == null) {
                return new DeviceDetails();
            }
            Type type = new TypeToken<DeviceDetails>() {}.getType();
            DeviceDetails deviceDetails = new Gson().fromJson(value, type);
            return deviceDetails;
        }

    }
    public static class ContentConverter{

        @TypeConverter
        public String stringFromContent(Map content){
            if (content == null) {
                return null;
            }
            String json = new Gson().toJson(content);
            return json;
        }

        @TypeConverter
        public Map<String, String> contentFromString(String value) {
            if (value == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();
            Map<String, String> content = new Gson().fromJson(value, type);
            return content;
        }

    }
}
```

But when I try to compile my code, this error message is displayed:

error: constructor DropboxPayload in class DropboxPayload cannot be applied to given types;

```
required: int,String,DeviceDetails,Map<String,String>
found: no arguments
```

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I just want to get the Model class without the id and thats why I have created a constructor without it. Can anyone explain how to accomplish that?

Comment: Does providing a no-argument constructor in `DropboxPayload` help?

Comment: @Glains can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Since you provide *setter-getter* for each property, there is no need to use *constructor* and if there is data for each property then room delivered it using *setter* method. So, better remove your *constructor*

Comment: Actually when I need to retrieve data from the table using DAO interface, I want to get the DropBoxPayload with the constructor where the ID is not present. I dont need that, how can I ignore that field ?

Comment: Don't use `id` anywhere in your code, that way you can ignore it. If you don't use it then why you bother about it?

Comment: Md.Asaduzzaman If I dont use id then multiple row will have the same value, how can I seperate them?

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a no-argument constructor in order to allow the framework to instantiate the class via reflection. By default, if you do not provide a constructor, a default one is implicitly added, but since you added your own, you have to add it explicitly.

```
public DropboxPayload() {

}
```

Comment: it solved the error, but how can I make it sure that when retreiving the data I need the parametered constructor to be used?

Comment: There should be no need to use it. JPA / Hibernate should initialize the fields for you. It uses the default constructor to create an instance and then sets all the fields referenced in your class that match the column names of your entities.

Comment: Actually when I need to retrieve data from the table using DAO interface, I want to get the DropBoxPayload with the constructor where the ID is not present. I dont need that, how can I ignore that field ?